# C-; and M-; are not working in Awesome Emacs Keymap

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed Awesome Emacs Keymap extension to my VSCode.

I'd like to use `C-;` and `M-;` commands to comment in and out, but they're not working. Where should I check to make them available?

Thanks for your advance.